# Issue in tf.data pipeline for TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-lab, tf.data.dataset

I have an application in which I need to setup a pipeline using tf.data. The data I have is stored in .mat files created in Matlab and contains three variables "s_matrix" which is a 224x224x3 double array, a "frame" which is 1024x1 complex double and finally a numeric label. The pipeline is to be loaded as such so that I can feed the data to the model.fit function. The code I have been using so far to load and process the data is added below but I keep getting several errors of type and unexpected byte errors.

**Update 2: Making several modifications**

Updating the code by including changes suggested by Giorgos and also changing the dataset generator and using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator function. There is some apparent improvement but now issue is that only one of the two inputs is being passed.

```
# Define the shape of the input image
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)

# Define the shape of the complex vector after conversion
complex_shape = (1024, 2, 1)

# Define a function to load and preprocess each sample
def load_and_preprocess_sample(sample_path):
    # Load the sample from the mat file
    sample = scipy.io.loadmat(sample_path)
    matrix = sample['s_matrix']
    complex_vector = sample['frame']
    label = sample['numeric_label']
    
    # Preprocess the matrix, complex vector, and label as needed
    real = tf.reshape(tf.math.real(complex_vector), [1024, 1])
    imag = tf.reshape(tf.math.imag(complex_vector), [1024, 1])
    signal_tensor = tf.concat([real, imag], axis=-1)
    signal_tensor = tf.reshape(signal_tensor, [1024, 2, 1])
    signal = signal_tensor
    # Normalize the matrix values between 0 and 1
    matrix = matrix / 255.0
    
    return matrix, signal, label
    

# Define a generator function to generate the samples
def sample_generator(file_paths):
    for file_path in file_paths:
        #yield load_and_preprocess_sample(file_path)
        matrix, complex_vector, label = load_and_preprocess_sample(file_path)
        yield (matrix, complex_vector), label
        
# Modify the create_dataset() function to use from_generator
def create_dataset(file_paths):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        generator=lambda: sample_generator(file_paths),
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=input_shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=complex_shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
        )
    )

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(file_paths))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return dataset

# Get a list of all file paths in the data folder
file_paths = [os.path.join(data_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_path) if f.endswith('.mat')]

# Split file paths into training and validation sets
train_file_paths = file_paths[:-num_val_samples]
val_file_paths = file_paths[-num_val_samples:]
```

Data generated and Model is called as below:

```
# Create datasets for training and validation sets
train_dataset = create_dataset(train_file_paths)
val_dataset = create_dataset(val_file_paths)
...
...
...
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train your model
model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=5,
          steps_per_epoch=num_train_samples // batch_size,
          validation_data=val_dataset,
          validation_steps=num_val_samples // batch_size)
```

the current error output is shared below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 90
     87 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     89 # Train your model
---> 90 model.fit(train_dataset,
     91           epochs=5,
     92           steps_per_epoch=num_train_samples // batch_size,
     93           validation_data=val_dataset,
     94           validation_steps=num_val_samples // batch_size)

File ~\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filea4_9b7hv.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\Admin\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 216, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing you have to do is to use dictionaries for input and output tensors. For example:

```
    dataset = dataset.map(
              lambda x: tf.numpy_function(load_and_preprocess_sample,
                                          [x],
                                          [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32]),
                                          num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda matrix, complex_vector, label: ({"input1": matrix,
                                                                  "input2": complex_vector},
                                                                 {"output": label}),
                           num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Providing datasets this way means that the `tf.keras.Input` layers you use to feed data should have the corresponding names. For example:

```
input1 = tf.keras.Input(..., name="input1")
input2 = tf.keras.Input(..., name="input2")
```

The same happens with naming the output layer. For example:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., name="output")
```

providing data this way means that you don't have to split input data and provide it as a list of inputs. You can simply do:

```
model.fit(x=train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, batch_size=5, epochs=5, validation_data=([X_test_a, X_test_b], y_test))
```

where `train_dataset` and `val_dataset` are the datasets returned from `create_dataset`.
Although you don't provide enough information to track what's wrong. What I would check first is what the logs say.

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_3_device_/job:
localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}}
0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float [[{{node PyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

The 0-th value that is double and not float, probably refers to `matrix`. I would try to cast this `matrix` to `tf.float32` as you declared in `tf.numpy_function` (which according to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function):

> Comparison to tf.py_function: tf.py_function and tf.numpy_function are very
> similar, except that tf.numpy_function takes numpy arrays, and not
> tf.Tensors. If you want the function to contain tf.Tensors, and have any
> TensorFlow operations executed in the function be differentiable, please use
> tf.py_function.
> you should probably change it to `tf.py_func`).

Also the 1-th element (`complex_vector`) is not what you processed (`signal`), thus you maybe have to change it to `signal` and probably cast ti also to `tf.float32`.

Another problem you may face is that the `sample_path` argument in `load_and_preprocess_sample` function may be read as a tensorflow string tensor so you should probably read the `sample_path` as `sample_path.numpy()`.
These are some ideas that you may consider to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I modified the code as per your suggestion to use dictionary, to use tf.py_func. I could not understand what you meant for complex vector not being what I processed in signal and conversion to tf.float32 as I believe all that is already being done. Nonetheless after the above mentioned changes, I now get the error "ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape."

Comment: I have also updated the question in which the code changes and new error message have been added

Comment: I mean that u return complex_vector which is assigned as complex_vector = sample['frame']. but As I can see you proccess it to signal variable.

Comment: Yes, the complex_vector is than passed to the signal variable after the real and imaginary components are extracted form the complex_vector and then reshaped to1024x2x1 before returning, that part is intentional...do you think there is any issue in that?

Comment: you return the complex_vector , not the signal variable so you return the not processed variable. I cannot say it simpler.

Comment: Oh shoot, I am so sorry I had that overlooked. Thanks. I'll modify and share the current progress here in a while

Comment: I have updated the question according to the most recent changes and error outputs. I also changed the "tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices" to "tf.data.Dataset.from_generator" as I believed that help solve the file path related issue you were mentioning as now I am at least getting one input to the model..

Comment: Have you tried the "dictionary method" to pass the inputs? Adding something like this:     dataset = dataset.map(lambda matrix, complex_vector, label: ({"input1": matrix,
                                                                  "input2": complex_vector},
                                                                 {"output": label}),                num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

Comment: I tried it at the start but dropped it due to some errors, I'll give it a try again

Answer (score 1):

```
training_dataset = list(train_dataset)
validation_dataset = list(val_dataset)
X_train_a, X_train_b, y_train = zip(*training_dataset)
X_val_a, X_val_b, y_val = zip(*validation_dataset)
```

This might help. Converting to list is important for iterating over the data.

Comment: Hey, I tried what you suggested but now I get the error at the list(train_dataset) function, rest error messages are similar to that shared above